# How to use replaceText

Tags: android

there is a protected method **replaceText** for **autocompletetextview** in Android.

I have no idea how to use it and need some examples.

Is it possible at all to use this method?!

Mur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is only used internally.

The setText method will replace the text in the box so I can't see why you'd need it anyway.

Comment: I just had problems with setText and onTextChangedListener. Everytime I called setText, it fired listener as well.

Comment: You might be able to dynamically adjust the contents of your autocomplete list somehow but setting a flag so that the listener knows it's not needed is probably easier.

Comment: Hmmmm ... can you give an example how to set a flag for listener or in activity?

Comment: Start by creating a Boolean member variable for example mSettingText

Comment: Give it a default value of false. In your onTextChangedListener function include something like:

    if(mSettingText) {mSettingText=false;return;}

Then, just before you call setText each time, set mSettingText to true. onTextChanged will still get called but won't actually do anything.